# Add contents of B.txt to some part in A.txt using sed or other command line tools?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to do as the title says: add all the text from B.txt to some specific place/part in A.txt.
Im trying to accomplish this using cat and sed but Im still novice with these tools and dont know if my goal can be accomplished with just these.

Here is a more visual command line idea i have:

```
cat A.txt | sed "s/some_part_in_A/some_part_in_A+contents_of_B.txt/" > C.txt
```

OR without cat...

```
sed "s/some_part_in_A/some_part_in_A+contents_of_B.txt/" A.txt > C.txt
```

OR something totally else...

concatenate A and B to get C.txt and then "move" somehow the B part of C (which would be at the bottom) to some part of A (of C). Hope that doesnt sound too confusing lol

What am I missing? Do I need to use some extra tools? What about variables? Somehow pop the contents of B.txt into a variable and then use that variable in sed?
Sorry Im kind of a noob at all of this, Im just trying to use some common sense to approach this problem. Some guidance would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
**SOLUTION**

For matching only **ONE LINE** and then inserting text from a file:

`sed '/some_part_in_A/rB.txt' A.txt > C.txt`

Thanks to Beta!

For matching **TWO LINES** (or more) and then inserting text from a file:

`sed "/line_one/N;/line_one\n.line_two/rB.txt" A.txt > C.txt`

Note, you first state line_one then N then line_one again followed by \n (and a . or wutever is necessary to capture anything inbetween \n and line_two, in my case a TAB char) and then line_two and finally r to "read" and thus insert the contents of B.txt into A.txt, but outputting the results to C.txt

Comment: Can you give us an example of `A.txt` and `B.txt`?

Comment: Its personal actually, but I dont see how its relevant? It could be anything.. Im looking for the **technique** here on how to "insert" txt from one file into another. I have no problem with the regex portion. I have setup my regex pattern to locate the place in A.txt where I want to place B's contents, so thats not an issue. The issue is in inserting B into A. Thats all. :)

Comment: I can't tell if you want to insert the lines from B into A, or if this could involve changes *within* a line. And what does the regex `/some_part_in_A/` look like exactly? Are you looking for a particular line, a word within a line, a line starting with something or other, what? Even a made up example would help.

Comment: Sure, /some_part_in_A/ is a line about half way in A.txt. Its actually this: `<div>Apple</div>` and I need to add some 50-100 lines (or more) from B.txt right after `<div>Apple</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '/some_part_in_A/rB.txt' A.txt > C.txt
```

Comment: what if I wanted to match TWO lines in A.txt and add B.txt after those two lines? Im having some trouble with sed doing that. ie. `sed "/<div>Apple<\/div>\n<li>/rB.txt" A.txt > C.txt` its like it doesnt understand \n ??

Comment: @StefanDjurcic: The only way I know is to use a command that spans two lines: `sed '/line_one/{N;/line_two/rB.txt<CR>}' A.txt > C.txt`

Comment: this doesnt work for me... complains about the <CR>, wut does that even do? a google search gave me nothing. btw im using GNU sed for Windows from [http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm] im thinking if this isnt so easy with sed what command would work for awk.exe or perhaps perl?

Comment: As I said, the command spans two lines, which isn't easy to show in a comment. "<CR>" means "carriage return", you shouldn't type it in verbatim.

Comment: nvm i got it to work! but I used something else/similar. since im on windows and using sed for windows, it doesnt like single quotes, nor {} sometimes, its weird. anyway, this formula worked for me using sed for windows 4.2.1 `sed "/line_one/N;/line_one\n.line_two/rB.txt" A.txt > C.txt` Note, you first state line_one then N then line_one again followed by \n (and a . or wutever is necessary to capture anything inbetween \n and line_two, in my case a TAB char) and then line_two and finally r to "read" and thus insert the contents of B.txt into A.txt, but outputting the results to C.txt